# Disable linting for specific JSON file

Tags: visual-studio-code

In VSCode is there any way to disable linting for a specific JSON file? Here are some extra words to make StackOverflow happy.

Answer (score 1):

It's not exactly what I wanted, but if you are willing to accept some limitations this kind of works:

Add the following to your settings:

```
    "files.associations": {
        "your_specific_file.json": "plain"
    }
```

It's probably best to add it to Workspace or Folder settings rather than global settings. It eliminates linting errors for that file. The downsides are:

- All files with that name in the workspace/folder have linting disabled.
- You also lose syntax highlighting etc. VSCode treats it as plain text.

Comment: you can add some linting on demand, by calling a command, with the extension I wrote: [JSON Validate](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=rioj7.vscode-json-validate)